# Creating a postgis database a GML application schema

Tags: postgis, open-source-gis, gml, software-recommendations

Is there any open Source tool(automated or semi-automated) that converts GML application schema to a POSTGIS database/table .Specifically I have a huge application schema containing many feature-collection which i would like to convert to postGIS database , through an automated process. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**[ShapeChange](http://www.interactive-instruments.de/shapechange/)** from **interactive instruments** already does a lot of useful things with enterprise architect application schema.

They are working on a DDL-tool for PostGIS. We discussed with them, to get a flat model what is good for GIS versus a relation model, better for data management. I think, we will get both soon.